# List all subsections in beginning of section

Tags: sectioning

I wish to start a section with a list of all subsections it contains. A list of all sub-sections' headers. Is there such a method to catch all subsection headers within the current section and display them?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `minitoc` package?

Comment: Do you want a kind of local ToC or only a kind of extreme page head? [`etoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) provides such local ToCs even for the sections of `book` or `report`. But without a MWE I'm not sure to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

We call that a »mini table of contents«. There are different solutions. As far as I remember, newer KOMA-script classes have a kind of solution implemented. And there are packages, like minitoc or etoc, as mentioned in the comments.

All solutions have their pros and cons, so it depends on what your are writing. I suggest that you provide a minimal example of your opus and ask a concrete question.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks people (@KeksDose, @AndrewSwann and @Schweinebacke). I found the `etoc` package useful and the following test code works and adds the intended sub-ToC (a mini ToC that shows the appendix subsections in the beginning of the appendix-section) ([live demo in ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\vspace{1cm}\hrule\vspace{1cm}

\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Appendix}

\localtableofcontents

\subsection{The first appendix}
\subsection{The second appendix}

\end{document}
```

The `\localtableofcontents` makes such mini-ToC for the current level in the hierarki in one go.

My next issue is to remove the auto-generated title `Contents` from the ToC. That will be for a new question after some more Google-searching.

---

**Update**

And the Google search plus some testing bore fruit. Of some reason, adding the very simple (and empty?) line `\etocsettocstyle{}{}` removes the title from the local ToC. Added just above the added local ToC:

```
...
\section{Appendix}

\etocsettocstyle{}{}    %% Removes title from \localtableofcontents
\localtableofcontents

\subsection{The first appendix}
\subsection{The second appendix}
...
```

Comment: Hello, is there a way to also remove the dotted line and page numbers only in the local TOC? I just want the subsection titles to appear.